# Cómo evitar inyección SQL en PostgreSQL con Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sql, inyección-sql

Quiero pasar un diccionario de python a una base de datos con un ciclo for, pero parte de los valores del diccionario tienen el apostrofe utilizado en SQL ('). Entonces cuando trato de ejecutar el script, yo mismo me causo una inyección sql.

```
dicc_esp_qu = {"clave": "valor que tiene un apostrofe en una palabra en quechua por ejemplo juk'uta"}

for clave, valor in dicc_esp_qu.items():
     miCursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO ES_QU VALUES('{clave}','{valor}')")
```

Intente transformando el diccionario a una lista y llevar la lista a una base de datos de forma protegida ante inyecciones:

```
dicc_esp_qu = {"clave": "valor que tiene un apostrofe en una palabra en quechua por ejemplo juk'uta"}
lista_dicc = []

for clave, valor in dicc_esp_qu.items():
    lista_dicc.append((clave, valor))


miCursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ES_QU VALUES(?,?)", lista_dicc)
```

pero haciendo de esa forma tengo un error de sintaxis:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «,»
LINE 1: INSERT INTO ES_QU VALUES(?,?)
```

Cuando creaba consultas de esta manera con sqlite3 no tenía problemas, pero parece que Postgre no acepta esa sintaxis. Como podría hacer para que la consulta considere esos apostrofes simplemente como una cadena de caracteres?

Comment: Si aun no llevas mucho de código en ese proyecto, te recomiendo que mires http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/, te ahorrarás muchos quebraderos de cabeza como ese.

Comment: Ok voy a leer la documentación muchas gracias!